# How can I pass a large number of command line arguments to C++ program

Tags: bash, shell

I'm using OpenCV 3.2 in Ubuntu 16.04 to stitch airborne scanned images. The example software that I'm using accepts the images as command line arguments so in order to stitch two images together I do the following:

```
./main image1.jpg image2.jpg
```

My problem is that I have a total of 96 images to stitch. Do I need to input each of these images separately or is there a way to give all files contained in a folder as command line input to C++ program?

I have not been able to Google suitable answer to this so I decided to ask here.

Comment: What does this have to do with OpenCV and C++? Unless I misunderstood your question, it's about Bash / shell usage.

Comment: Well I just tried to be specific on what I'm doing and with what. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: For example: `./main image*.jpg`

Comment: `image*.jpg` will expand to all jpegs starting with "image", similarly to `ls image*.jpg`. Basic shell usage.

Comment: Other little more flexible alternative is `find folder -type f | xargs ./main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the shell file name expansion by entering

```
./main image*.jpg
```

`image*.jpg` will be expanded by the shell to all jpeg files starting with "image", similarly to `ls image*.jpg`.

So if you have 96 files called `imageXX.jpg`, your main program will receive all 96 files on the command line.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I know how =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

dir_path=$1

if [ $# = 1 ]; then

    if [ -d "${dir_path}" ] ; then

        echo "$dir_path exists and is a directory";
    else
        echo "$dir_path is not a directory";
        exit 1
    fi 
else
    echo "Need one argument = directory";
    exit 1
fi

echo "Process all files";

image_names=" ";

# concat all .jpg files in directory
FILES="$dir_path/*.jpg"
for f in $FILES
do
  # echo "Processing $f file..."
  image_names+=" $f"
done

echo "run ./main $image_names";

exec "./main $image_names";
```

save it as "runAllFiles.bash" in the directory that contains your "./main"
then open a terminal in this directory and write command line

```
bash runAllFiles.bash myfolder
```

Where "myfolder" is the path to your folder with images.jpg

Comment: Thank yo very much! =)